# CoffeeScript for PHP/HTML to convert the coffee to php/html minified script

Tags: php, coffeescript

Good day, I'm new to coffeescript and happy about the features.

I would like to know if there such thing as CoffeeScript for PHP View Layer, and something from .coffee to .php as minified form.

something like:

```
td:
  Wow
```

to:

```
<td>Wow</td>
```

Or something ways to preserve the ORIGINAL CODE to a MINIFIED .PHP file

Comment: something a way to convert original code to a minified form?...im usjng coffescript inside sublime package control and it will automatically convert .coffee to .js...while I'm looking for something the same for PHP that will minify the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP-Jade is what you need.

Jade is actually better in javascript enviroment
but it is also available for php syntax.

https://github.com/opendena/jade.php

Here more examples.
http://everzet.github.io/jade.php/

Comment: thanks for that, any add-ons to make the html tags to a minified html scripts?

Comment: You can use grunt for that kind of job.